# Split a single DXF file into parts

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, autocad, dxf

I am using the netDxf library to read and modify simple 2D DXF files in C#. As I need to "plot" them with a marking laser which only has a working area of around 80x80 mm, I have to split input files with larger structures into parts of that size. The output should be DXF files as well.

Is there a simple solution reusing code already implemented or do I have to write my own slicing algorithm?

Comment: i think this should be a basic function of laser plot software.